# changing display of some divs by clicking on li

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have a menu
i have some divs and i want change the display of my divs to none execpt the div which is related to the menu item that is clicked.
i wrote some codes but it didnt work and changed all of my divs display to none
here is my codes

```js
var myValue, number, newArray;
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

$(".BreakfastLi").click(function() {
  myValue = 1;
})

$(".LunchLi").click(function() {
  myValue = 2;
})

$(".DinnerLi").click(function() {
  myValue = 3;
})

$(".DesertLi").click(function() {
  myValue = 4;
})

$(".SoupLi").click(function() {
  myValue = 5;
})

$(".DrinkLi").click(function() {
  myValue = 6;
})
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

  newArray = myArray.filter(num => num !== myValue);
  number = newArray[i];

  $(".group" + number).addClass("d-none");

}
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="foodMenu">
  <li class="BreakfastLi">Breakfast</li>
  <li class="LunchLi">Lunch</li>
  <li class="DinnerLi">Dinner</li>
  <li class="DesertLi">Desert</li>
  <li class="SoupLi">Soups</li>
  <li class="DrinkLi">Drinks</li>
</ul>



<div class="group1">some content</div>
<div class="group2">some content</div>
<div class="group3">some content</div>
<div class="group4">some content</div>
<div class="group5">some content</div>
<div class="group6">some content</div>
```

Comment: The `for` loop is not run on each click. You might want to start by fixing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want the show/hide code to run on each click. You don't really need `myValue` or `myArray` at all though.

```js
function showGroup(i) {
  $(".group").addClass("d-none");  // hide all groups
  $("#group" + i).removeClass("d-none");  // show selected group
}

$(".BreakfastLi").click(function() {
  showGroup(1);
})

$(".LunchLi").click(function() {
  showGroup(2);
})

$(".DinnerLi").click(function() {
  showGroup(3);
})

$(".DesertLi").click(function() {
 showGroup(4);
})

$(".SoupLi").click(function() {
  showGroup(5);
})

$(".DrinkLi").click(function() {
  showGroup(6);
});

showGroup(0); // hide everything by default
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="foodMenu">
  <li class="BreakfastLi">Breakfast</li>
  <li class="LunchLi">Lunch</li>
  <li class="DinnerLi">Dinner</li>
  <li class="DesertLi">Desert</li>
  <li class="SoupLi">Soups</li>
  <li class="DrinkLi">Drinks</li>
</ul>
<div class="group" id="group1">some content 1</div>
<div class="group" id="group2">some content 2</div>
<div class="group" id="group3">some content 3</div>
<div class="group" id="group4">some content 4</div>
<div class="group" id="group5">some content 5</div>
<div class="group" id="group6">some content 6</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

AKX got you on the right track, but classes are intended to be sets of like things. Let's use one and element index to vastly simplify.

- https://api.jquery.com/index
- https://api.jquery.com/eq

The caveat with this is that the quantity and order of the group elements needs to correspond to the list items, but that's a common strategy and is less fragile than managing what amounts to a bunch of arbitrary ID values.

```js
function showGroup(i) {
  $(".group").addClass("d-none"); // hide all groups

  if (i !== null) {
    $(".group").eq(i).removeClass("d-none"); // show selected group
  }
}

$(".meal").click(function() {
  showGroup($(this).index());
})

showGroup(); // hide everything by default
```

```css
.d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="foodMenu">
  <li class="meal">Breakfast</li>
  <li class="meal">Lunch</li>
  <li class="meal">Dinner</li>
  <li class="meal">Desert</li>
  <li class="meal">Soups</li>
  <li class="meal">Drinks</li>
</ul>

<div class="group">some Breakfast content</div>
<div class="group">some Lunch content</div>
<div class="group">some Dinner content</div>
<div class="group">some Desert content</div>
<div class="group">some Soups content</div>
<div class="group">some Drinks content</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's vastly simpler, and has the implicit assumption that the menu's order corresponds to HTML element order.

Comment: @AKK replacing 12 lines of repetitive (see DRY) code with a single line - yes, much simpler and *vastly* less prone to errors, along with this being data-driven code (ie, add a new meal+group doesn't need any new code).  I do agree that HTML element order can be an issue, but probably not here.